# Bootstrap Logo doesn't shrink when resized

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently been developing a webpage for my business, and have been asking questions to aid the self - development, called Empreus.

I am using bootstrap to help me design the page. 
However, I have now reached a problem.

The code I have so far is shown in the code snippet.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    src: url('montserrat-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('montserrat-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('montserrat-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('montserrat-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('montserrat-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('montserrat-light-webfont.svg#montserratlight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratsemi_bold';
    src: url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.svg#montserratsemi_bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#header {
 padding:10px 0 0 0 ;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
 
 .navbar-brand {
  display:none;
 }
}

.navbar {
 margin-bottom:0px;
 font-family:"montserratlight";
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-top:2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 border-radius:0px;
}

img.logoEmpreus {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display:block;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

img.logoEmpreus:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
    animation-name: rubberBand;
}

#page {
 margin: 0px auto;
}

li {
 display:inline;
 margin:0 -1px;
}

li a {
  color: black;
  font-size:16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size:18px;
  text-decoration: none
}

li.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none
}

ul {
 margin:0 auto;
 font-family:"montserratlight";
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.active {
 font-family:'montserratsemi_bold';
}

.imageInside { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 {
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 0.8em 'montserratsemi_bold', Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translateY(-50%);
} 

#base ul {
 margin:0 auto;
 border-top:2px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
 padding:10px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family:"montserratlight";
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Problems | Stack Overflow</title>
  <!-- Tab Title -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div id = "header">
   <!-- Empreus logo Image. Animated. Width 300px. -->
   <img class = "logoEmpreus animated" src = "http://bit.ly/1P2ZlbH" alt="Empreus" width="300" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
   
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
           <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
           <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stack Overflow</a>
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
           </div>

           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active"><b>The Problem</b></a></li>
             </ul>
           </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </nav>

   <div class = "row">
   <!-- Declaration of First Row -->
    <div class="imageHolder col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px;"> 
    <!-- Image Container as DIV -->
     <div class = "imageInside hvr-underline-from-center" >
      <h2><span>Logo Issue.</span></h2>
      <img id = "imageHomeJPG" src="http://bit.ly/1P2Ylo3" style="width:100%" />
     </div>
     <!-- Image Link -->
       </div> 
   </div> 
   
   
   <div class="row">
   
   <div id = "base" class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:10px">
     <p>
      <ul class="col-md-12"> 
       <!-- MAIN NENU BAR -->
       <li><a href="#">Copyright Whatever</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Unordered lists.-->
     </p>
   </div>
   <!-- Navigation HTML Markup -->
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now, here is the problem. 
The webpage viewed on an iPhone 6 device appears as such.
[image: iPhone 6 & 6 plus]

However, on an iPhone 4/ iPhone 5, the logo moves out of the container (see below)
[image: iPhone 4 & 5]

I want the logo to be within the container width, just like normal for the iPhone 6 & 6 plus example. I was thinking whether it would be possible to add some code to make the logo flexible but I so far tried to use `min-width` which made no effort.

Can anyone help?
I have inserted the code as a snippet. Please do view it in full screen. 
I used the chrome inspect element & resize to simulated screens function to get these screenshots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width hard-coded into the image tag may have tripped you up; it would override any CSS in your stylesheet. You could use a combination of `width` as a percentage and `max-width` set to the actual width of the image:

```
<img class = "logoEmpreus animated" src = "http://bit.ly/1P2ZlbH" alt="Empreus" />

img.logoEmpreus {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Snippet below (For the sake of brevity, I removed some of the HTML/CSS not necessary to duplicate the issue):

```css
#header {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: "montserratlight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
img.logoEmpreus {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
img.logoEmpreus:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
#page {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}
li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none
}
li.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none
}
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "montserratlight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <!-- Empreus logo Image. Animated. Width 300px. -->
  <img class="logoEmpreus animated" src="http://bit.ly/1P2ZlbH" alt="Empreus" />
</div>

<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stack Overflow</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="active"><b>The Problem</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>



</div>
```